# How to find a json object in a json array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of json objects like such

```
[{firstname: "Tom", lastname: "Smith"}, {firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Smith"}]
```

I would like to find whether an element in that array is located in a User object with field names that also contains an array of json objects.

An example of the User object is

```
{ "names": [{firstname: "joe", "lastname":"smith"}, {"firstname": "john", "lastname":"doe"}]}
```

and I would like to find out if any of those names objects are contained in an array of random length called list2 of format below

```
[{firstname: "Tom", lastname: "Smith"}, {firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Smith"}, {firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Smith"}, {firstname: "Jordan", lastname: "Smith"}, {firstname: "John", lastname: "Smith"}, {firstname: "Bill", lastname: "Smith"}]
```

How would I create a mongoose query to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that your array you are searching is called "list", if your objects always contain both of and only those fields you can do this with the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```js
{ 
    "names": {
        "$in": [
            { "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" }, 
            { "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith" }  
        ]
    }
}
```

If those objects are going to possibly vary and have additional fields then you can do this with [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) and [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```js
{
    "$or": [
        { "names": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" } 
        }},
        { "names": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith" } 
        }},
    ]
}
```

If you want to find documents that contain **both** of the objects, swap the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator for [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

### Update

What you seem to be struggling with is how this applies in your program. Of course we never actually hard code queries like this, we just use the data types to construct them. So if your data actually matches the conditions given for the use of $in then your code looks something like this:

```js
// A list array that you likely actually retrieved from somewhere else
// so you don't actuall define it here

var list = [
    { "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" }, 
    { "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith" }  
];

// and the query "using" the array
db.collection.find({ "names": { "$in": list } })
```

Where you need to use the other form, then the "building" becomes a little more complex:

```js
// A list array that you likely actually retrieved from somewhere else
// so you don't actuall define it here

var list = [
    { "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" }, 
    { "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith" }  
];

var query = { "$or": [ ] };

// process the list to add conditions
list.forEach(function(item) {
    query["$or"].push({ "names": { "$elemMatch": item } })
});

// submit the constructed "query" object to find
db.collection.find( query );
```

Comment: mongoDB gotcha: `{ "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" }` !== `{  "lastname": "Smith", "firstname": "Tom" }`   // NOTE order!  So you would have to include both permutations in the `$in` method mentioned.  `$elemMatch` does not require the permutation (it ignores the order).

Comment: but the thing here is I don't want to list out the other list like "$in": [
            { "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" }, 
            { "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith" }  
        ] Instead, it's an array of unknown length that has multiple firstname and lastname objects.

Comment: @std What part of the answer does not address that? Did you try? Neither form asks you to list everything, just the items you want to match.

Comment: you're explicitly naming the objects as in {
    "$or": [
        { "list": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith" } 
        }},
        { "list": { 
            "$elemMatch": { "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith" } 
        }},
    ]
}

Comment: what if list2, the array you plan on finding list elements in contained a bunch of firstname, lastname json objects, but you weren't actually sure of the length of list2.

Comment: What I want is to match any element from list1 that is also contained in list2, but I don't want to enumerate the objects in list2 or list1 because I'm not actually sure what they are. I just want to make a match. Does that make sense?

Comment: @std It does make things difficult to understand with the way you have changed the question. What are you trying to do? a:) Match a list of random length to find fields in a "name" array? b:) Match a "name" array in the document with another field called "list2". I'm leaning towards (a) here and therefore the answer still applies even though you may not understand how, which can be explained further if needed

Comment: Thank you, your first bunch of code made me understand what mistake I was doing when adding $in to my mongoose query.